# R - Cleaning a broken CSV file

Tags: r, csv, data-processing, data-cleaning

I've posted a question the other day and realized I didn't formulate my problem very well. So I've cleaned it up and made it simpler.

```
"@realdonaldtrump","19301000","19300609","Jody"
"@realdonaldtrump","1350700000","1350725479","Bobby
Fischer"
"@realdonaldtrump","870440000","870442502","Lenny"
Phone</a>"
"@realdonaldtrump","4831200000","4831194209","Tom"
"@realdonaldtrump","4.397e+09","4397021841","Dave"
"@realdonaldtrump", "12345678","9012345678", "Zee
G

Zeek"
```

I have CSV data with some problems. I need to clean it so I can read it in with R.

What I expect back is 6 entries, one for each Jody, Bobby Fischer, Lenny, Tom, and Dave, Zee G Zeek.

However, that pesky Phone" artifact is screwing things up.

So my first thought was to gsub that out.  Problem is, that artifact varies across millions of entries.  Sometimes its Phone".  Sometimes its Eck".  Sometimes its Twitter".  Various lengths.  Various formats.

The other problem is, in the case of things like "Bobby Fischer", a line from above may have a \r\n in the middle of an important field.  I don't want to LOSE these lines.

Is there a clear method that exists to clean out these problematic lines, while not destroying the beneficial lines that just happen to extend down?

Comment: Do your artifacts contain a comma? If not, you can preprocess the file with sed or awk or some other command line editor and remove all lines without a (or two or three) comma somewhere. (or are there actually linebreaks in the names?)

Comment: how big is your data set, i.e. is it feasible to suck the whole thing into memory simultaneously via `readLines()` or should we be advising you about command-line tools (grep, sed, awk, cut) as suggested by @Roland?

Comment: It's a large file (500 MB) but can be read into memory all at once on my setup.  Command line editor is fine (working on Windows if it helps).  The file is multi-million lines, but all of these artifacts I've found do not contain commas yet.  The lines that are "good" that are just multi-line due to embedded newlines DO have comma, however.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the `fread` function from the *data.table* package which has a `fill` parameter. By setting this parameter to `TRUE`, you will create separate rows for those *pesky* cases you want to remove eventually while at the same time retaining fields with `\r\n` inside.

Supposing the data is in `twit.csv`:

```
library(data.table)
twit <- fread('twit.csv', fill=TRUE, header=FALSE)
```

will give:

```
> twit
                 V1         V2         V3             V4
1: @realdonaldtrump   19301000   19300609           Jody
2: @realdonaldtrump 1350700000 1350725479 Bobby\nFischer
3: @realdonaldtrump  870440000  870442502          Lenny
4:       Phone</a>"                                     
5: @realdonaldtrump 4831200000 4831194209            Tom
6: @realdonaldtrump  4.397e+09 4397021841           Dave
7: @realdonaldtrump   12345678 9012345678 Zee\nG\n\nZeek
```

Next you could filter out the wanted values with `grep`:

```
twit[grep('^@', V1)]
```

which will give you:

```
                 V1         V2         V3             V4
1: @realdonaldtrump   19301000   19300609           Jody
2: @realdonaldtrump 1350700000 1350725479 Bobby\nFischer
3: @realdonaldtrump  870440000  870442502          Lenny
4: @realdonaldtrump 4831200000 4831194209            Tom
5: @realdonaldtrump  4.397e+09 4397021841           Dave
6: @realdonaldtrump   12345678 9012345678 Zee\nG\n\nZeek
```

Comment: I'm trying this, but I always get "unused arguements (fill = TRUE).  I tried referring to the documentation http://127.0.0.1:26532/library/data.table/html/fread.html but fill doesn't seem to be listed anywhere.

Comment: @Jibril The `fill` argument is currently only available in the development version of *data.table* (which I am using). See [here for installation instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for lines that do not start with `"` while the last line was closed with `"`.
Search for

```
\"\r\n[^\"]+\"
```

replace it by

```
\"\r\n
```

Comment: Hey!
Thanks for the suggestion, but that would ruin lines like the Zeek example if it was condensed so that the Zeek was on the very next line.

Comment: Hey! I wanted to add, and this worked on like 90% of my cases!  Some of them are a little tougher though.  This is because some of my tweets have ""quotes"" for some reason.  For example "I concur\r\n \r\n ""I believe in God who can change people- he can make any of us better.""\r\n@RealBenCarson", theRest, ofThe, commaDelimited, file.  Any idea how to catch that?  The case where a line that does not start with ", while the last line was closed with ", except for when its ""?